# Как правильно сделать выборку с двух таблиц?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица gamefication
http://prntscr.com/kwmqns
В ней список всех "заданий" для пользователей.

Есть таблица customer_gamefication
http://prntscr.com/kwmr9q
В ней хранятся id пользователей, которые выполнили какие-то из заданий.

**Мне нужно вывести все данные с таблицы gamefication(Все задания) и вписать совпадения с customer_gamefication по определенному пользователю(customer_id)**

Я попытался сделать и все верно вывело, но в результат попали другие пользователи, хотя я указал WHERE customer_id
http://prntscr.com/kwmta3

Comment: Зачем UNION в запросе?

Comment: 1. Так customer_id вы указали только в запросе с inner join, в запросе с left join условие на customer отсутствует. 2. оформите вопрос соответствующим запросом - картинку вложить в тело вопроса (не ссылку кинуть) и написать запрос кодом здесь (а не скриншотом).

Comment: @Pavel, выложите скрипт таблиц gamefication и customer_gamefication

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение:

```
SELECT g.id, 
       g.step_id, 
       g.name, 
       cg.customer_id, 
       cg.status, 
       cg.date_added 
FROM oc_gamefication g
  LEFT JOIN oc_customer_gamefication cg 
    ON (g.id = cg.gamefication_id 
      AND cg.customer_id = 26854)
```